# PHP: Store Result of JavaScript Function into a PHP Variable

Tags: php, mysql

Please bear in mind, I'm very new to PHP.  I've only started taking it this semester at my school.

Here's what I want to eventually do: I have a senior project where I'm building a computer repair system.  In the repair MySQL table, I have a bunch of fields and one of them is CustomerID (so I know which customers had which repair).  I want to have a drop drown of customer's names, and then when I click on it, some how attach that customer's ID to a variable so I can do an INSERT statement.  In order to partially achieve this, I've done things in smaller parts.  The small part I have working is when I select a dropdown value, it outputs it to the screen, but that's in the javascript function.

Here's my code:

```
<?PHP
include('session.php');
$db_name = "";
$mysql_username = "";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_server = "";
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, 
$db_name);
$query = "SELECT custID, CONCAT(custFirstName, ' ', custLastName) as 
Customer_Name FROM customer";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

echo "<select name ='names' id='myselect' onchange = \"myFunction()\">";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value = '" . $row['custID'] . "'>" . $row['Customer_Name'] . "
</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<p>When you select a customer name, a function is triggered which 
outputs the ID of the selected customer.</p>
<p id=\"demo\"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById(\"myselect\").value;
document.getElementById(\"demo\").innerHTML =  x;
}
</script>"; 

$content = "<script> document.write(x) </script>";

echo "<br> <br> The technician ID = $sTechID <br> <br> The customer ID = $content";
?>
```

I can output the ID to the screen with the Javascript function, but when I try to store "x" into a php variable, it doesn't work.  In chrome, the inspector says that X is undefined.

A side note: I made a test file with this code and it worked:

```
<?PHP
echo "
<script> 
var x = \"hello\"
</script>";

$content = "<script> document.write(x) </script>";

echo "$content <br> <br> $content";
?>
```

Because the above code worked, I don't understand why my bigger code is not working.

I understand that my code is a mess, but any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript) (the title does not represent the answers in that question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a back-end language and can't detect front-end events such as click, change, etc.

In your larger code, the value of `x` will only be defined once the event is fired(`onchange`), that's when the `select` input changes. Javascript works that way, but PHP doesn't. Once PHP sends a response the first time, its job is done.

This is when you will want to use forms or Ajax. 
Using forms would be a good start.

Quick note, it's good practice to try to keep HTML, CSS and JS separate from PHP as much as possible.

```
...
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

?>

<form method='post' action='insert.php' /> <!-- Link to php file to insert data to database -->
  <select name ='names' id='myselect' onchange = "myFunction()">
  <?php 
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<option value = '" . $row['custID'] . "'>" .  $row['Customer_Name'] . "
               </option>";
      }
  ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" /> <!-- You will need a button to submit the data -->
</form>

<p>When you select a customer name, a function is triggered which 
outputs the ID of the selected customer.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

And now your `insert.php` file would look like:

```
<?php 

// Get data from that was posted from the form
$customer_id = $_POST['names'];

// Now do whatever with the customer ID
echo $customer_id;
```

Comment: [Here](http://phppot.com/jquery/php-contact-form-with-jquery-ajax/) is a AJAX tutorial you can follow

Comment: Thanks for your input! Being that it's Thanksgiving, I'm taking a break from it for now. I will resume later. Will your answer work without AJAX?

Comment: Thank you SO much. I took what you added, added it to the php file I had already and was able to manipulate it to suit my project. Much more to do, but this is a giant huddle I've stepped over. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a better understanding of PHP in general. PHP is executed BEFORE the browser executes the html/js that you've echo'd to it. The reason this works:

```
<?PHP
echo "
<script> 
var x = \"hello\"
</script>";

$content = "<script> document.write(x) </script>";

echo "$content <br> <br> $content";
?>
```

is because you are writing JS to the dom and it's being executed once your browser reads it. If you run a `var_dump($content);` you will see that what you have stored in that PHP variable is not the result of `x` but actually a literal string that contains the text `"<script> document.write(x) </script>"`.

The line `echo "$content <br> <br> $content";` prints `"<script> document.write(x) </script> <br> <br> <script> document.write(x) </script>";` to the DOM, which in turn is run as JS in the browser.

If you want your drop down selection to do something in PHP I would suggest triggering a JS function on change of the drop down that in turn sends an AJAX request to a separate PHP file that does what you need to do there and returns it to your function. This way you can update the HTML without navigating to another PHP page.